# Datepicker works unexpectedly on Server

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, razor, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I was working on my localdatabase on a ASP.NET MVC 5 and I was using a datepicker. It was working perfectly. This is how it looks when it works on local database :

[image]

This is how it works on server :

[image]

Moreover, when I pick a date on server. It says :

> The field ProjectDeadline must be a date.

This is my datepicker code :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProjectDeadline, new { @class = "date-picker"})
```

This is in _Layout.cshtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // This will make every element with the class "date-picker" into a DatePicker element
        $('.date-picker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy" });
    })
</script>
```

I get these errors when I press F12 on browser :

> ```
> GET http://example.com/Content/base.css Create:12
>
> GET http://example.com/Content/theme.css 404 (Not Found) Create:12
> ```

Here is my CSS and JS references :

```
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

<!-- At the bottom of the body -->
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Can you tell me how to fix this situation? Could some script have not been uploaded to server when publishing? I did a web publish. Everything seems normal except this situation. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the CSS is not referenced. Can you please check that the css is properly referenced. Check console for that. Also it may be the fact that subdirectory hosting could be breaking the path reference

Comment: @TusharGupta Could you give more detail on what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: Share how you have referenced your CSS in your layout.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I edited my question.

Comment: @jason: Have a look at your server where you have deployed your project. Under Content folder both `base.css` and `theme.css` are available or not because error is self  describing `404 (Not Found)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I published my project in **Debug** mode, the problem was solved.